# Are there any NIST curves with pairings?

Tags: elliptic-curves, pairings, nist, standards

NIST FIPS.186-4 has standardized 5 ECC curves on field  (P-192, P-224, P-256, P-384, P-521) and 10 elliptic curves on binary fields. None of them seem to have pairings. Are there any standard curves which support pairings?   Are there any libraries which support those curves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there any standard curves which support pairings?

No, there are currently no pairing-friendly NIST curves; NIST has not announced any plans to approve of either a pairing-friendly curve, or any cryptographical operation that involves a pairing operation.

Comment: Why is it so? Pairings are used in many schemes right. NIST is now conducting competitions for lattice-based crypto. I'm surprised why it is not caring for more practical pairing-based crypto.

Comment: IRTF via the CFRG group is working on some pairing friendly curves. They have several drafts involving curves and protocols using them